# iOS Game Center - Does it use local high score after adding to a future build?

Tags: ios, game-center

I finished a game, but I do not have Game Center implemented yet.  I will be doing so at a later build, but my game does store high score values on the device.

When I do add the Game Center, will the high scores already saved on the device be used for Game Center, or are there specific values that only Game Center can use which will cause everyone to have to create their high score again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to submit your previous high scores to Game Center.

Game Center leaderboards can take many different formats, from [the Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html):

> Game Center provides three basic formatting types:
>
> An abstract number, such as an integer or a fixed point number.
>
> A time value, such as minutes or seconds.
>
> A monetary value, such as dollars or euros.

All you need to do is add code to submit the high score to Game Center once it is integrated with your app.

Once you update your game, in the `AppDelegate`'s `ApplicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method you can add something like this:

```
if ([NSUserDefaults standardUserDefualts] objectForKey: @"High Score Submitted"] == nil){
    // CODE TO SUBMIT HIGH SCORE TO GC
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: @"Yes" ForKey: @"High Score Submitted"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I actually have the game built in Unity, and I am not sure where would I even place the code in xcode.  I will look into seeing how I can do this in C# first through Unity.  If I can't figure it out I will certainly be back here to ask.